# Minima & maxima of Laplace's equation

Tags: electrostatics, potential

I don't get the following sentence from David J. Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics* (the ambiguous sentence is in bold)

> Laplace's equation tolerates no local maxima or minima; extreme values
>   of $V$ must occur at the end points. Actually, this is a consequence of (1), 
>   for if there were a local maximum, $V$ would be greater at that point than
>   on either side, and therefore could not be the average. (Ordinarily, you
>   expect the second derivative to be negative at a maximum and positive at a
>   minimum. Since Laplace's equation requires, on the contrary, that the sec­ond derivative is zero, it seems reasonable that solutions should exhibit no
>   extrema. **However, this is not a proof, since there exist functions that have maxima and minima at points where the second derivative vanishes:
>   $x^4$ for example, has such a minimum at the point $x = 0$.)**

Comment: But the example $V(x)=x^4$ is not a [harmonic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function). Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/191449/2451

Answer (score 2):

I think what Griffiths meant was that

"Since Laplace's equation requires, on the contrary, that the sec­ond derivative is zero, it seems reasonable that solutions should exhibit no extrema."

But it does not necessarily mean that a function cannot have a null second derivative in an extremum, since the $x^4$ function has a minimal value at the same point the second derivative vanishes.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions of laplace equation have neither maxima nor minima except at boundaries. This is because the second derivative must be greater than or less than zero for maxima or minima but it is equal to zero as per laplace equation(here i have assumed only 1 degree)

Answer (score 0):

In 2D, an extremum requires both second derivatives have the same sign (negative for a maximum and positive for a minimum). Same thing in 3D (all three second derivatives must be same sign).